# Source for iterating through all words of english dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary

I need to iterate through all words of english dictionary & filter certain based on whether they are noun/verb or anything else & certain other traits . Is there any thing I could use as a source for these words ?

Comment: What English dictionary? are you looking for that dictionary? if not are you receiving "word objects" that contains information like its value, if it's noun/verb... or just the plain word without any other information? Do you already have some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I recommend [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/) from princeton.edu.** It is a popular English lexical database with word attributes such as:

1. Short definition
2. Part of speech, e.g. noun, verb, adjective, &c.
3. Synonyms and groupings

There is a [WordNet Java API](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html) from smu.edu that will simplify using WordNet in your application. You might also download the database and parse it yourself, as its only 12MB compressed.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to mention, with regards to WordNet, there are 'stop words' which are not included.  Some people online have made lists of stopwords, but I'm not sure how complete they are.
Some stop words are: 'the', 'that', 'I', 'to' 'from' 'whose'.

A larger list is here:
http://www.d.umn.edu/~tpederse/Group01/WordNet/wordnet-stoplist.html

For a list of words see this sourceforge project:
http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/

You may also want to search for the *usecases* of such a list, in order to find a suitable data source.

For instance:

- Spell checking algorithms use a word list (stand alone spell checkers, word processing apps like OpenOffice, etc).
- Word game algorithms use words (Scrabble type games, vocabulary education games, crossword puzzle generators)
- Password cracking algorithm use words to help find weak passwords.
  outpost9.com/files/WordLists.html

Also there are several Java APIs to choose from, and only some work with the latest dictionary (3.1)  The one by MIT uses Java 5 and words with WordNet 3.1.